# How to detect if a particular command has executed in terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, fedora

I need to detect if a particular command has run. for example if I do a `git push` I need to execute a build script in my fedora machine. Is there any way to do this.? we can use any facility in linux. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) is what you're looking for?

Comment: Alternatively you could use [auditd](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/chap-system_auditing.html) system service, check this [topic](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84847/is-there-an-easy-way-to-log-all-commands-executed-including-command-line-argume) on http://unix.stackexchange.com. But I would stay with simpler, task-oriented methods like git hooks as long as you can.

Comment: You can run desired command under the wrapper file. This wrapper file should start with touching a flag file. And it should ends with removal of that flat file. Now you can run audit for presence of that flag file. May be it help, is you want to go bashonly.

Answer (score -2):

You can try using "alias", try this link http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-aliases-mac-centos-linux-unix.html

Comment: for example : alias git push='/path/to/script'

Comment: That's not a valid alias definition.

Comment: Why no? In ~/.bashrc file??

Comment: Try running it at the command line; you can't put spaces in the name of an alias.

Comment: Sure ok, but it was to explain with the same example